# From Pandas series, create dictionary with unique elements as keys, and their indices as values

Tags: python, pandas

The goal is to create a dictionary from a pandas column (series) where the keys are the unique elements of the column, and the values are the row indices in which the elements occur. I currently have code that accomplishes this, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler and less hacky way to do it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
idx = df['A'].reset_index().groupby('A')['index'].apply(tuple).to_dict()
```

Comment: I think that line is pretty neat if you ask me. Didn't you work on something similar here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49011261/fastest-way-to-combine-two-slices-from-two-pandas-dataframes-in-a-loop/49053835#49053835

Comment: Yes, and I've been using this method since then, but I'm wondering if there's any more pythonic way.

Comment: If @Jezrael can't do it, I quit coding.

Comment: I am going to test but I think this the best way

Comment: could you use a Series instead tuple or list?

Comment: @ALollz This is what I've been looking for! Thank you! I've never heard or seen ".groups" before!

Comment: Yes, it's a very uncommon thing. The attribute is hidden at the very bottom of the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html#pandas.Grouper, with no real description of what it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the `groups` attribute of a GroupBy object. It returns a dict with unique values as the keys and `Index` objects of the Original DataFrame.

```
df.groupby('A').groups
```

---

```
{0: Int64Index([61, 466, 505, 619, 697, 811, 872], dtype='int64'),
 1: Int64Index([125, 254, 278, 330, 390, 396, 670, 732, 748, 849, 871, 880, 882,
                908, 943], dtype='int64'),
 2: Int64Index([77, 283, 401, 543, 544, 693, 816], dtype='int64'),
 ...}
```

Or if you really need the tuples:

```
{k: tuple(v) for k,v in df.groupby('A').groups.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
d = {x : y['index'].tolist() for x , y in df.reset_index().groupby(list(df))}
```